# Big O notation preserved under convex functions?

Tags: distributions, stochastic-processes, bounds

Suppose that the random variable $X_T$ is $O_p(1)$ as $T \rightarrow \infty$. Does this imply that the random variable $\max\{0,X_T \}$ is $O_p(1)$?

Comment: Short answer, yes. You can prove it directly using $O_P(1)$ definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X_T=O_p(1)$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $M$ such that

$P\{|X_T|>M\}<\epsilon$

So, fix $\epsilon$ and take corresponding $M$. Then

$P\{|max(0, X_T)|>M\}\le P\{|X_T|>M\}<\epsilon$